# Entity Framework and models/validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have just used Entity Framework for the first time, using this example :

http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/creating-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-aspnet-mvc

I have previously used MVC without the Entity Framework, and I am wondering where the models and validation that I used in MVC with LINQ come into things with the Entity framework.  Where are your model classes and validation located in the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC and Entity Framework are two different things. you can validate your view models in MVC layer by using data annotators . http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs